# Find row for cell with a value from an array - Google scripts

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have a database, on which I want to find the row index depending on if the value in the first column belongs to another array of values

Say column A and B have the following values:
A: 111, 112, 113, 114, ...
B: 112, 113

I want to find the row(s) in column A that has a value within the array of values on column B.

Here is my code thus far. The problem: The indexOf is not detecting the values, and returns = -1 when tested in the Logger.log function

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
  values = sheet.getRange(7,2,5,1).getValues(), //This would be 'Column B'
  rows = sheet.getLastRow();


for (var i = 2; i <= 15; i++){
  Logger.log(values);
  Logger.log(sheet.getRange(7,1).getValue());
  Logger.log(values.indexOf(sheet.getRange(7,1).getValue()));

  if (values.indexOf(sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue()) != -1) { //column 1 because 'Column A'
    Logger.log("Success");

  }
}
```

Using the Logger.log function I've been able to prove that the value it's pulling actually DOES match one of the values in the array... But for some reason, it doesn't detect it...

For my purposes, I have also tried the following:

```
for (var i = 2; i <= rows; i++){
  for (var j = 1; j <= values.length; j++){
    if (values[j] == sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue()){
      Logger.log("values[j] works. Found in cell " + i + ",1 con un valor que busco");
    }
  }
}
```

But here, the Logger.log function is not being called, which means that the if statement is not being met, representing the same main problem. The array value in the cell tested is not being able to meet with one of the values in the array.

Thanks in advance for your help. I've really searched for hours now, and can't seem to find the answer for this particular problem...

For what it's worth, the reason I'm trying to do this is because I want to update the database depending on the number of entry (In this example, column A), but only update certain rows (The ones I indicate on column B).

Comment: @I'-'I is correct... `getRange(7,1,5,1)` is a range that begins in A7 (row 7, column 1) and is 5 rows long and 1 column wide, i.e. `A7:A12`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. The example was adapted to simplify it, but maybe I did a bad job at it. Originally, 'values' comes from a different sheet, so the only important thing is that it's a source of values that is supposed to be a different range from where I'm looking to find it.
Sorry about that!

Comment: I changed it to make it less confusing... Sorry again..

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly. If so, just comment and we could work out a code.

You get -1 out of your `indexOf` function because it can't search a two-dimensional array. The `join()` function could help; this summes your two dimensional array into a string. Your index of function can search the one-dimensional string and your `logger.log` function should give you the correct result.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot @JoeL31
This was absolutely all I needed. For future reference and readers, this was the solution.
In the code, when using `values.indexOf(...)` I just switched it to `values.join().indexOf(...)` and now it detects the cells correctly!
I'm really thankful JoeL31!

Comment: Well, I have a new problem now, @JoeL31
It's detecting each part of the string as what I'm looking for.
Say I'm looking for number 454. It's detecting as "correct" the rows that have number 4, number 45, and number 54 in them, which kind of would go against my purpose to update them accordingly.
Do you have any ideas as to how to make it detect only if the whole string is met?

Comment: Can you check if this rather dirty solution works for you?                                    `.join()`  gives you commas inbetween the parts of the string https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join Can you try `indexOf("," + word)`. So just set a comma before your word of choice.

Comment: Had to tweak it a little, but it works!
The thing is that, as you say, `.join()` separates the parts by commas, so I had to add them on both sides of the `.indexOf("," + valuesImLookingFor + ",")`... Thus, it only works if the values are repated. Because of the nature of my data, it's no problem, but for further reference, if someone is looking to do this for values that are just available once some times, you can work around it with a simple `if`statement checking the `values.length()` before running the `.indexOf()`, and when length is just 1, do a simple `if (range == values)`.Thanks JoeL!